# Is it possible to make the height of an image responsive (without js)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 Bootstrap columns. The left one has text, the right one an image.

Depending on resolution the text will change in height. The image will stay the same height. So on high resolutions the image will extend far beyond the text and on low resolutions the text will extend far beyond the image.
With Bootstrap's img-responsive class the image will shrink on lower resolutions.
I actually would want the image height to automatically change with the height of the text. Is there a CSS way to do this?

[what I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQTer.jpg)

By popular request ;) (I also already tried setting it to height: auto btw) :

```
    <div id="about" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2 id="ab2">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div>
                <img src="_public/_images/img3.png" alt="img3" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give us some code to work with?

Comment: are you using the correct class `img-responsive`?

Comment: Yes. But please provide a code sample.

Comment: probably with display:table and display:td, also try Flexbox

Comment: Is it possible to make this question clear? I am reading it 5th time and have no clue of what you want.

Comment: @skobaljic OP wants the image to stretch with the text, not making it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not called "responsive". You want the image to stretch with the text. The best way is through making it a background image. The image I'm using is 350x150, as you can clearly see, but it is stretched to cover the 33.333% of space horizontally and 100% vertically.

However, I personally would never stretch any image because it is one of the "no no" of designing.

```css
#special-background {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
  background-size: 33.333333% 100%;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="about" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2 id="ab2">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="special-background">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want text and image section (div) height looks same in all screen..

> [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

and if you want to hide image in any view use bootstrap classes:

below 767px use **hidden-xs**

768px to 990px use **hidden-sm**

990px to 1199px use **hidden-md**

above 1199pxpx use **hidden-lg**

may be this answer will help you..

Comment: Doesn't really do what I want it to do. (I've added an img showing what I'd want it do be)

But thanks for pointing out that Bootstrap already has those hidden classes built in, I had already written my own lol.